# Implementing a Custom Loss Function in TensorFlow for Regression Problem with Group-Specific MSEs

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, regression, user-defined-functions

I am working on a regression problem using TensorFlow, where I have encountered a challenge with my loss function. My data points are structured as triples $(Y_i, G_i, X_i)$, where
$Y_i \in \mathbb{R}$ represents an outcome; $G_i \in {0,1}$ is a binary group identifier; $X_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is a feature vector.

The goal is to train a neural network that predicts $\hat{Y}$ given $X$, using a custom loss function that is the absolute difference in Mean Squared Errors (MSE) between the two groups.

Formally, the loss function for a prediction algorithm $f \colon \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined as
$$e_k(f) := \frac{\sum_{i \colon G_i=k} (Y_i - f(X_i))^2)}{\sum_i 1{G_i=k}}.$$
The loss is then $|e_0(f) - e_1(f)|$. Alternatively, minimizing $(e_0(f) - e_1(f))^2$ is equivalent.

I am struggling to implement this loss function in TensorFlow, as it is not a straightforward sum of individual data point losses. The challenge lies in the loss depending on multiple data points across both groups.

My main questions are

- How can I structure this loss function in TensorFlow, considering its dependence on group-wise calculations?
- Are there any specific TensorFlow functions or techniques that would simplify the implementation of such a group-based loss function?
  Any guidance or suggestions on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

### What I tried

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


def custom_loss(group):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        # reshape
        y_pred = tf.reshape(y_pred, [-1])
        y_true = tf.reshape(y_true, [-1])

        # Create a mask for each batch
        mask_b = tf.equal(group, 1)
        mask_r = tf.equal(group, 0)

        y_pred_b = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, mask_b)
        y_pred_r = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, mask_r)
        y_true_b = tf.boolean_mask(y_true, mask_b)
        y_true_r = tf.boolean_mask(y_true, mask_r)

        # Ensure same data type
        y_pred_b = tf.cast(y_pred_b, y_true.dtype)
        y_pred_r = tf.cast(y_pred_r, y_true.dtype)

        mse_b = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true_b - y_pred_b))
        mse_r = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true_r - y_pred_r))

        return tf.abs(mse_b - mse_r)
    return loss


# Since the loss depends on the group average, batch_size should be sufficiently large (?)
def train_early_stopping(model, custom_loss,
                         X_train, y_train, g_train, X_val, y_val, g_val,
                         n_epoch=500, patience=10, batch_size=1000):
    # Initialize variables for early stopping
    best_val_loss = float('inf')
    wait = 0
    best_epoch = 0

    for epoch in range(n_epoch):
        if epoch == n_epoch-1:
            print('Not converged.')
            break
        loss_epoch_list = []
        for step in range(len(X_train) // batch_size):
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                start = step * batch_size
                end = start + batch_size
                if end > X_train.shape[0]:
                    break
                else:
                    X_batch = X_train[start:end]
                    y_batch = y_train[start:end]
                    g_batch = g_train[start:end]

                    y_pred = model(X_batch, training=True)
                    loss_value = custom_loss(g_batch)(y_batch, y_pred)
                loss_epoch_list.append(loss_value.numpy())
                grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)
                model.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

        # Calculate validation loss for EarlyStopping
        val_loss = custom_loss(g_val)(y_val, model.predict(X_val))
        print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}: Train Loss: {np.mean(loss_epoch_list)}, Validation Loss: {val_loss}")

        # Early stopping check
        if val_loss < best_val_loss:
            best_val_loss = val_loss
            best_weights = model.get_weights()
            wait = 0
            best_epoch = epoch
        else:
            wait += 1
            if wait >= patience:
                print(f"Early Stopping triggered at epoch {best_epoch + 1}, Validation Loss: {best_val_loss}")
                model.set_weights(best_weights) 
                break


# Create a synthetic dataset
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=20000, n_features=10, noise=0.2, random_state=42)
group = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=y.shape)  # 1 for 'b', 0 for 'r'
X_train_full, X_test, y_train_full, y_test, g_train_full, g_test = train_test_split(X, y, group, test_size=0.5, random_state=42)
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val, g_train, g_val = train_test_split(X_train_full, y_train_full, g_train_full, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# main
num_unit = 64

model_fair = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_unit, activation='relu', input_shape=(X.shape[1],)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_unit, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model_fair.compile(optimizer='adam')
batch_size = X_train.shape[0]//5

train_early_stopping(model_fair, custom_loss, X_train, y_train, g_train, X_val, y_val, g_val,
                     patience=10, batch_size=batch_size)
```

The code executes without generating any error. However, the training, validation, and test set losses differ significantly, indicating potential issues with the training process.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to account for batch dimension in your loss function. Your group variable has dim as whole Y set, while function `y_pred` passed to your loss function has dim as batch. You probably want to generate your mask with the size of batch, either from within the loss function (different every time), or as it is now, just with the batch size.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insightful comments! Following your advice, I've revised the code (updated in the original post as I couldn't include it in this comment) which implements a custom training loop. The code executes without generating any error. However, I'm facing a new issue: the training, validation, and test set losses differ significantly, indicating potential issues with the training process.  I would greatly appreciate it if you could suggest any possible reasons for this behavior, or any further adjustments I might need to consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in the initial code was solved by Pawel -- thank you so much!
The modified code in the question worked well after making the following changes:

- choose a much smaller batch size (e.g. 64)
- change the loss from the absolute loss to the squared loss
- shuffle the train set for each epoch -- this is not necessary but improves the result